# Do I have to check row count after insert?

Tags: java, mybatis

I saw code like below.

```java
public void insertSomething( SomeObj some ) {
  // insert 1 row
  int result = someMapper.insertSomething( some );

  if( result != 1 ) {
    throw new SomeException( "insertion failed" );  
  }
}
```

I'm curious about `if( result != 1 ) { ... }`.

Wouldn't a database exception raised if the database failed to insert something?

Do I have to remove this code or not?

Comment: I think this is just MyBatis carrying the result of `Statement.executeUpdate()`. And this is not just about affected rows (inserted, updated, etc.), but also about ddl statements that affect no data. If you know that you're inserting just one record, then perhaps you should simply have a try/catch around your insert call and raise your `SomeException` when you catch an sql exception of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single line INSERT the result is unnecessary. The Database will throw an exception if the INSERT fails.

Comment: If I insert more than two line, is it necessary?

Comment: If you insert multiple lines, it can be useful to compare the affected lines with the lines that should have been inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time - it depends on implementation. Lots of ORM done in a state - where insert returning `boolean` value - whether information was inserted or not. So, basically, your example with `result != 1` checking exactly - whether data was inserted in DB or have not.